# Python subprocess.call error message with check_output

Tags: python, subprocess

So I have:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['wine',
                    os.getcwd()+'/static/sigcheck.exe',
                    '-a','-i','-q',
                    self.tmpfile.path()])
```

But whenever I run this I get this error

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['wine', '/home/static/sigcheck.exe', '-a', '-i', '-q',     '/tmp/tmpxnsN5j']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

But if I change `check_output` to `call` it works fine:

```
Z:\tmp\tmpvOybcm:
    Verified:       Unsigned
    File date:      9:08 AM 10/24/2012
    Publisher:      Hardcore Computer
    Description:    Farthest Emitters Converter
    Product:        Farthest Emitters Converter
    Version:        3.2.0
    File version:   3.2.0
fixme:mscoree:StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx (L"Z:\\tmp\\tmpvOybcm", 1, 0x33ec13): stub
    Strong Name:    Unsigned
    Original Name:  n/a
    Internal Name:  Farthest Emitters Converter
    Copyright:      Hardcore Computer 2006
    Comments:       n/a
```

Any reason why `check_output` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A non-zero return code is (usually) a way of indicating exit with error by a program.  So `subprocess.check_output` will raise an exception if the returncode of the process is non-zero.  If you use:

`retcode = call(...)`

and then print the return code I guess you will see that it is returning 1.

Comment: is there a way to capture the output into a variable?

Comment: You can use `check_output` in a `try:` block and `Except CalledProcessError:`, but the usual way is just to make a `subprocess.Popen` object with pipes for stdout, stderr and then use it's `communicate` method.

Answer (score 3):

To get output in a string without raising an error on non-zero exit status:

```
p = Popen(['wine',...], stdout=PIPE)
output = p.communicate()[0]
```

`check_output()` executes `rc = p.poll()` after `p.communicate()` and raises an error if `bool(rc) == True`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['wine',
                    os.getcwd()+'/static/sigcheck.exe',
                    '-a','-i','-q',
                    self.tmpfile.path()], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = proc.stdout.read()
```

Comment: It is preferred to use `communicate()` rather than `.stdout.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Comment: Roger. Thanks for the warning